# grid.Focus, TextBox and Delete key interaction?

Tags: wpf

I have the following code (a `TextBox` is focused by default):

```
    private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl))
        {
            if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.S))
            {
                grid.Focus();
                ModifyPart(sender, e);
            }

            if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Delete))
            {
                grid.Focus();
                DeletePart(sender, e);
            }
        }
    }
```

The Ctrl + S combination trigers, but Ctrl + Delete won't. Instead it deletes the contents of the `TextBox`(which I programmatically highlighted by default). I replaced `Delete` with `Enter` and it works, so I guess `Delete` key has some sort of a higher priority over everything else.

If I move `grid.Focus();` out and above the `if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Delete))` method, then it works, but I lose functionalities of `Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V, Ctrl+P`, etc, because I'm removing focus from the `TextBox`.

Any idea how to overwrite the `Delete` priority?

Comment: try PreviewKeyDown event

Comment: and set true to Handled after you handled https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.handled?view=net-5.0

Comment: Could you elaborate what `e.Handled = true;` does in this case, because changing KeyDown to PreviewKeyDown worked? Shouldn't releasing the `Ctrl` button act as `e.Handled = true;`?

Comment: Answering my own comment: In my case `e.Handled = true` makes the `grid.Focus();` redundant. Before, without  the `grid.Focus();`, if I decided to cancel the `ModifyPart(sender, e);` action, the `S` key would get passed onto the Textbox, replacing the highlighted text in the process, same applies to the Delete key. By adding `e.Handled = true`, I don't have to remove focus from the Textbox anymore, because the keystroke doesn't get passed onto it, if I decide to cancel the action.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @ASh and @Soleil - Mathieu Prévot answers.

XAML:

```
PreviewKeyDown="Window_PreviewKeyDown">
```

CS:

```
private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{

  if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
  {
      this.Close();
  }

  if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl))
  {
      if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.S))
      {
          ModifyPart(sender, e);
          e.Handled = true;
      }

      if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Delete))
      {
          DeletePart(sender, e);
          e.Handled = true;
      }
  }
}
```